# How is a dual boot with grub supposed to be configured?

Tags: linux, debian, dual-boot, grub

I've seen some instructions but I'm really trying to understand the whole boot process. I installed debian on a drive with a partition for the OS and another partition for the user. It automatically created boot and swap partitions also. Then, using gparted, I created a new partition cloning the original debian partition. I gave it a new UUID. I updated grup options.

When I boot, I get to the grub options and I see two versions of the os. I specifically select the OS on the new partition. But when it boots and i check in the terminal, i see / is mounted from `/dev/nvme0n1p2` instead of `/dev/nvme0n1p5`

This is what I'm confused about:
`/dev/nvme0n1p1` mounts to `/boot/efi` and in `/boot/efi/EFI/debian/grub.cfg` there is a config file:

```
search.fs_uuid FIRST-DRIVE-UUID root 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg
```

What this basically means to me is that it's going to mount the first install, then load the grub.cfg from that first install. Now it's already got the first install mounted as root, but to run the second install, it obviously needs to mount the second drive as root instead. So it seems like it's loading grub from within the first install instead of loading grub BEFORE it mounts the first install?

There is a grub config file that references both installs at `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` , but this is part of the first install's partition. It seems like once this file is read, the first install has already loaded and it's too late to select which partition to boot from. This file starts with

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
```

Does this config somehow need to be moved to the boot partition?

When I run update-grub or grub-mkconfig (v2.04-20) i get this output:

```
$ sudo grub-mkconfig -o grub.cfg 
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found background image: /usr/share/images/desktop-base/desktop-grub.png
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-9-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-9-amd64
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-8-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-8-amd64
Found Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) on /dev/nvme0n1p5
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

This would appear to reference the initrd and vmlinuz on the first install. the second install just gets `found`.

Comment: `Does this config somehow need to be moved to the boot partition?` - no, what you posted tells you exactly what is going on - the file is generated by `grub-mkconfig` from the indicated templates and settings - perhaps you should read the documentation for `grub-mkconfig`

Comment: I read this. What I'm confused about is why there are two configs, one being simpler than the other, and why it has to mount the partition with the first install before it can give me the option to mount/boot into the second install.

Comment: You have two grub installs, but one one will boot from UEFI. Both installs when updated will offfer to boot all other installs. But you have to update both installs with every kernel or grub update. Also UUID/GUID issues often make it easier just to do another install, rather than trying to copy & edit an install. You have to have correct UUIDs in grub, fstab & maybe some other places like recovery from swap. I have multiple installs but add my own boot to 40_custom to reduce edits. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1332570/how-do-i-stop-grub-from-scanning-particular-disks/1332664#1332664

Comment: I added the output from that script, but not the cfg itself.

Comment: @oldfred thanks, that make a little more sense, i did try updating my UUIDs manually in fstab, but looking in the /boot/grub/grub.cfg it looks like it always says to mount the first install as the root.  both installs have a /boot directory and i think that should really be on a shared partition with the cfg file, so then it would decide which partition to mount as root at that time. is that right?

Comment: With multiple installs, you also cannot share a /boot (kernel conflicts) and should not share a /home (settings conflicts). You can share a data partition. You need to check GUID/partUUID with efibootmgr & lslbk, and UUID with lsblk, fstab and all grub entries. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1195682/boot-problem-in-uefi-multiboot-system-with-separate-drives-in-ubuntu-18-04/1195984#1195984

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Mounting a filesystem" is a Linux/Unix concept: it does not really exist in GRUB.

Specifying a `$prefix` or `$root` for GRUB is not really like mounting a filesystem in Linux/Unix. They are literally just prefixes to relative or absolute pathnames, respectively.

`$prefix` is used when GRUB is loading any GRUB modules, and it can also be used as a convenient variable to refer to any file in (what will ultimately be once the OS is booted) the `/boot/grub` directory by absolute GRUB pathname. When the GRUB `insmod` command is used, it takes the value of `$prefix`, and adds an architecture-specific directory name and the name of the module to load (with the `.mod` suffix added).

GRUB has its own (read-only) filesystem drivers that accept absolute pathnames of the form `(`partition`)`/directory...`/`filename, where the partition component can be something like `hd0,gpt1`.

`$root` can be assigned and re-assigned multiple times within a single GRUB configuration file; in modern configurations, the `search` command is usually used for it rather than an explicit assignment, to allow specifying a filesystem by its UUID.

On a Debian 9 system (using BIOS-style boot) I once saw a GRUB configuration that initially set `$root` and `$prefix` to load some GRUB modules, then pointed `$root` to a separate `/usr` partition in order to load a background image and a font file from a GRUB theme directory somewhere in `/usr/share/...`. For the actual boot options, it then pointed `$root` back to the `/boot` filesystem for loading an actual kernel, or to a Windows partition to chainload its partition boot record.

GRUB's `$root` has nothing to do with the Linux root filesystem. Once GRUB has loaded the Linux kernel and the initramfs file into RAM, it will hand over control to the kernel. At that point, only three things from GRUB will be preserved:

- the kernel in RAM
- the initramfs in RAM after the kernel
- the boot options specified on the kernel command line.

All the GRUB variables, including `$root` and `$prefix`, are totally forgotten at that point and cease to have any meaning. As the kernel starts up, it will activate its own storage device drivers, and the filesystem that will be mounted as the Linux root filesystem is determined by:

- the `root=` kernel boot option, if one is specified, or
- the contents of the initramfs file (it might include a copy of `/etc/fstab` that specifies the root filesystem, or scripts that determine the filesystem to use in some other way), or
- the default root filesystem may be specified by parameters built into the kernel image (especially if a custom kernel with no initramfs is used).

---

The UEFI version of GRUB will normally look for `grub.cfg` *in the same directory where `grubx64.efi` is located in*. The three-line `grub.cfg´ you found in` /boot/efi/EFI/debian/grub.cfg`effectively tells GRUB where the actual GRUB configuration file (and the`/boot/grub`directory) is, by filesystem UUID. If you wanted, you could replace the UUID with the UUID of the`/dev/nvme0n1p5`filesystem, to make GRUB use the`/boot` of that instance of Debian instead of the first installation.

---

If you have the `os-prober` package installed in Debian, it will automatically run whenever you run `update-grub`, and will attempt to auto-detect other operating systems, including parallel installations of Debian, and add their principal boot options to the GRUB configuration file.

You also could add a menu item like this to your `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` on `nvme0n1p2`:

```
menuentry 'Switch to GRUB configuration of /dev/nvme0n1p5' {
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root UUID-OF-nvme0n1p5-FS-HERE
        configfile /boot/grub/grub.cfg
}
```

and similarly in `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` on `nvme0n1p5` to switch back to GRUB configuration of `nvme0n1p2`. Remember to run `update-grub` to allow the changes take effect.

Then you can set the `search.fs_uuid` line in `/boot/efi/EFI/debian/grub.cfg` (i.e. in `nvme0n1p1`) according to which configuration you want GRUB to use by default. As long as both instances of Debian keep using a similar enough version of GRUB to accept the same configuration files,  you will be able to easily toggle between the two OS instances, and they will both be able to maintain their own GRUB configuration files independent of each other.

Comment: Wow - thank you for writing that all out. Most of that made sense to me. I'll give it another read and see if that information helps me solve the problem. thanks!